# Como fazer um auto update recorrente corretamente?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Eu estou criando um pequeno jogo de browser e recentemente me surgiu uma dúvida sobre como fazer um valor do banco de dados ser manipulado (consultado/atualizado) a cada segundo, mesmo com o usuário desconectado.

Tenho no meu banco de dados uma tabela chamada `recursos` com as colunas `ouro` e `ouroPorSegundo`.

O jeito que consegui fazer funcionar é criando uma página própria apenas para o servidor, nela usando o `setTimeout` para, a cada segundo, chamar uma página PHP que da um update no banco de dados.

Esse jeito de se fazer está correto? Penso que talvez fique sobrecarregado quando se usa esse método várias vezes (uso ele também para checar se as tropas/unidades já voltaram para a "base" depois de feito um ataque), além que preciso manter uma página aberta no servidor pra ficar atualizando os dados de todos os usuários.

**Edit:**
O jogo deve funcionar no estilo de `tribal wars`, `ikariam`, eles usam algum sistema que a cada segundo o banco de dados é alterado, pois você pode receber um ataque de um outro jogador, e dependendo o segundo que receber o ataque o ouro roubado tem um valor diferente.

Estou fazendo dessa forma, na página do servidor:

```
$(function() {       
    getStatus();
});

function getStatus() {       
    $('div#status').load('getstatus.php');
    setTimeout("getStatus()",1000);      
}
```

getstatus.php:

```
$select = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM player_resources WHERE id = 1");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($select) >= 1) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
            $ouro_hora = $row['ouro_hora'];
        }
        $ouro_seg = $ouro_hora / 60 / 60;
    }

    $update = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE player_resources SET ouro = ouro + $ouro_seg WHERE id = 1");
```

Como disse está funcional, mas a dúvida é se é o jeito correto de se fazer.

Comment: Olá Fadu, acho que suas  chances de receber uma boa resposta melhoram bastante com um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Está um pouco difícil de entender o que você está fazendo, mas se a ideia é executar *updates* contínuos em uma tabela com dados apenas disponíveis do lado do cliente um *web service* sendo chamado por requisições AJAX não é "errado", apesar de *long polling* e *websockets* escalarem melhor em boa parte dos cenários (veja [essa resposta em Inglês para maiores detalhes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10029326/664577).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entendi o que quer fazer, mas não é assim que se faz. Tente imaginar um [MMORPG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_role-playing_game), imagine a quantidade de *hits* que seu banco de dados irá sofrer caso tenha milhares ou milhões de usuários.

Para esse caso, o mais simples de se fazer é, a cada vez que houver uma transação MANUAL nos recursos do personagens, vc grava o saldo atual e a hora que aconteceu. Ex:

`10/08/2016 11:52:30 100G`

Supondo que no seu game o personagem ganhe `1G` a cada 1 segundo, se eu for consultar meu saldo 12h00, a consulta retornará `550G`, mas no banco continuará gravado o mesmo registro acima - `100G às 11:52:30`. Se 12h00 eu gastar `130G` comprando algo, por exemplo, então uma transação MANUAL irá ocorrer, e apenas atualizo no banco o saldo atual.

`10/08/2016 12:00:00 320G`

E, de novo, quando eu for consultar o saldo a 12:01:40 por exemplo, irei ver que tenho `420G`. Pois basta fazer o calculo antes de exibir.

Desta forma seu game somente irá fazer atualizações no banco de dados quando houver transação MANUAL de recurso, e não a cada segundo/player - o que tornaria seu game inviável. E também somente irá consultar o banco e fazer os cálculos quando um player estiver jogando, for isso seu banco descansa.

Do jeito que você estava pensando me fazer, se eu criar um personagem e depois nunca mais voltar a jogar, seu script continuará sendo executado para meu personagem, todos os dias, a cada segundo, para sempre.

***UPDATE***

No caso do player ser atacado, para saber a quantidade de recursos que ele possui, basta consultar o status do saldo e calcular o saldo atual. Por exemplo, se o status do saldo é `10/08/2016 12:00:00 320G`, a hora do ataque for `10/08/2016 18:15:40`, então o saldo atual é de `21.960G` - considerando o ganho de `1G` por segundo.

Comment: Eu entendo seu ponto, mas quanto ao banco só "funcionar" enquanto o player estiver online não seria uma opção, pois se por exemplo ele ficar um dia inteiro sem entrar no jogo, ele deveria continuar ganhando seu ouro a cada segundo, porque um outro jogador poderia ataca-lo e dependendo da hora (cada segundo faria diferença) que ele atacasse, o roubo de ouro seria um valor diferente.
E quanto ao jogador ficar sendo atualizado para sempre, eu pensei em se ele ficar inativo por, por exemplo, 7 dias, o jogo excluiria ele do banco de dados e com isso ele pararia de receber atualizações.

Comment: @Fadu, adicionei um complemento na resposta. Veja se ajuda.

Comment: acredito que isso pode resolver, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que entendi você tem um *script* sendo executado para atualizar informações no banco mesmo quando o usuário não esteja conectado, certo? Se for isso mesmo,você pode fazer um script em PHP simples que apenas altera as informações do banco, retirar o *timeout* e colocar o script para ser executado no **CRON** do seu servidor. O único problema aí é que o tempo mínimo do **CRON** é de 1 minuto.

Comment: O tempo deveria ser a cada segundo mesmo, pois se um outro jogador atacar ele, ele irá roubar o ouro do outro e cada segundo faria toda diferença, pode ser o tempo que o jogador levaria pra gastar seu ouro antes de receber o ataque.
O jogo funcionaria no estilo tribal wars/ikariam, eles tem algum sistema que funciona desse jeito.